# Xdebug giving me and error: Failed loading /usr/lib/php/modules/xdebug.so

Tags: php, xdebug

Complete error is:

> Failed loading /usr/lib/php/modules/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/modules/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_memory_peak_usage

When i try to check if i have it installed with:

```
php -i | grep "xdebug"
```

The server runs on `PHP 5.1.6`

Comment: 5.1.6 is WAY outdated. Upgrade your PHP version

Comment: I can't do it, it's not my server